# How to optimize filter query across multiple tables

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-performance

I need to implement a filter in a database with a scheme quite complicated. I have created here a reduced example, recreating the tables [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/7e061).

### The model

I will try to explain more or less what this model does:

- `center_table`: every row in this table it's an "instance" of one object.
- `field_*_definition`: these tables contains the different field definitions of an  object.
- `field_*_values`: these tables contains the different field values of the object/field which they point to, in `center_table`.

So, an example. If we have an object, for instance `Table`, that has four fields (from type `a` to `d`). Then we will have one row in each one of the `field_*_definition` tables.

Now, if we have 100 instances of tables, we will have 500 additional rows in the database:

- 1 row per table instance. 1 row per field (every field pointing to the table instance AND the field instance).

### Problem

We want to get the rows from `center_table` that satisfies some filtering conditions. For instance, get all the table instances whose field with name `number_of_legs` of the `Table`, it's between 3 and 5.

### Current Solution

We would solve that as follows. Given the field id is 4 (we can assume we always know this), then the query would be:

```
SELECT id FROM center_table WHERE
id IN (SELECT id FROM field_c_values WHERE field_definition_id=4 AND value BETWEEN 3 AND 5 );
```

### Scalability of the solution

As you may guess, if we continue to extend this solution, it becomes a problem. Let's get the query more complicated step by step. Imagine we filter by two different fields in `field_c_values`. The query would be something like:

```
SELECT id FROM center_table WHERE
id IN ((SELECT id FROM field_c_values WHERE field_definition_id=4 AND value BETWEEN 3 AND 5) INTERSECT (SELECT id FROM field_c_values WHERE field_definition_id=1 AND value BETWEEN 1 AND 6));
```

We need to use `INTERSECT` because both conditions to be true. Now, to add more complexity, let's consider a query where apart from those filters, we also consider the same in all the different field types. So we basically need to copy paste that query for times:

```
SELECT id FROM center_table WHERE
id IN ((SELECT id FROM field_c_values WHERE field_definition_id=4 AND value BETWEEN 3 AND 5) INTERSECT (SELECT id FROM field_c_values WHERE field_definition_id=1 AND value BETWEEN 1 AND 6))
AND id IN ( ... another intersection of subqueries... )
AND id IN ( ... another intersection of subqueries... )
AND id IN ( ... another intersection of subqueries... );
```

And as you can see, this is slow has hell because we have a ton of subqueries.

### The question

So, I want to know how to make this filtering more efficient. I have been taking a look at `LATERAL` joins but I do not really know if they can solve this. Any ideas? If you need more information or more clarification please tell me so.

Comment: You have been bitten by the EAV pattern. You'll have to live with it or redesign your database.

Comment: It's strange how often people that don't want to use an RDBMS, use an RDBMS.

Comment: I know... The best thing about it is inherit the project... I do not know how costly would be to change this to a document database.